# Update Cells in Google Sheets based on the current date

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query

I want to update the cells in a Google Sheet if the current day is before a specific date that is marked in another sheet.

I have a sheet with all the data, along with sheets for each month. When the data sheet is updated, I want the sheets for each month to update as well, unless the current date is after that month.

For example, if today is January 1st and I update a cell in data, I want all sheets for each month to update. But if today is March 6th and I update the data sheet, I want sheets for March - December to update, and I want Jan - Feb to remain as they are (not get emptied).

Basically at the end of the year, each sheet should be fully filled out with the last data available during that month. I'd prefer if I could do this without a script, but I'm not against using a script for this. Am I going about this the right way? Is it only doable using queries or scripts, or can I do it with a bunch of other comparisons? I've tried queries but I'm new and can't quite figure out the right syntax.

Comment: Scripts only___

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without scripts by using the TODAY() function.

Just use an if statement, such as = if( [date in a different cell] >= today(), [operation if true], [operation if false] )

If you want it to go by month, it would be if( month(date in different cell) >= month(today()).